# Allowing a user to sign pdf file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have a pdf file and want to allow user to upload a gif file of their signature and display the signature in my pdf file...

pls follow the link
http://support.persits.com/pdf/demo_fill.aspx

http://www.asppdf.com/livedemo.html -> template fill out

Answer (score 2):

You can use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to insert an image in a PDF.  See the example: [iTextSharp - Working with images](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images).

Comment: thnx bill.. this really helped me.. but i have a issue in this... the issue is that the code is overwriting the existing content in the pdf file... i want to display the image on a certain location appending it in the existing content...

Comment: thnx bill.. you gave me a good start.... helped to win 90% of my battle... my issue is resolve now.... below are the links that really helped to resolve my prbhello all,

the following links helped to resolve my problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583629/how-can-i-insert-an-image-with-itextsharp-in-an-existing-pdf
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372542/itextsharp-and-putting-rich-text-in-a-specific-position
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images
http://asp-net-whidbey.blogspot.com/2006/04/generating-pdf-files-with-itextsharp.html